# Left join big DataTables in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, join, datatables

I have 3 big tables in SQL Server:

- Table1 (ID1, ..., ID2) => around 3 million rows
- Table2 (..., ID1, ...) => around 50000 rows
- Table3 (..., ID2, ...) => around 8 million rows

The first table is the "main" table, the second table has the foreign key to the first one (ID1), and the third table has a foreign key also to the first one (ID2).

I loaded them into three DataTables in program, and need to do left join of this three tables.

I already did it with linq, in this way:

```
var defaultRow = table2.NewRow();

for (int i = 0; i < table2.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    defaultRow[i] = DBNull.Value;
}

var leftJoin1 = from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
                join t2 in table2.AsEnumerable() on t1["ID1"] equals t2["ID1"]
                into tableGroup
                from item in tableGroup.DefaultIfEmpty<DataRow>(defaultRow)
                select new
                             {
                                 ID1 = t1["ID1"],
                                 Column12 = t1["Column12 "],
                                 Column13 = t1["Column2"],
                                 ... Column118 = t1["Column118"],
                                 Column21 = item["Column21"],
                                 Column22 = item["Column22"],
                                 ...
                                 Column29 = item["Column29"]
                                };

foreach (var row in leftJoin1)
{
    var newRow = table1Table2.NewRow();
    newRow.ItemArray = new object[] { row.ID1, row.Column12, row.Column13, ..., row.Column118, row.Column21, row.Column22, ..., row.Column29 };

    table1Table2.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

This works for me - first I do left join on table1 and table 2, and than left join on joined table (table1table2) and table3 in the same way, and get joined table1table2table3.

My problem is performance. When I do this join on such a large datatables, It lasts very long. First two datatables aren't problem, but join with the third sometimes never ends, unless I set them some filter - in that case join finishes for few minutes.

I searched for a long time how to do this and not to set them filter (to reduce the number of rows) and couldn't find an answer.

Is there any way I can do left join on these three big datatables in C# faster?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you loading them all and joining them via code? Why don't you just query the exact data you want straight from the database?

Comment: Because I have to reduce the load on the database and try to speed up the search on these tables (data from all three, at once, are required) by loading into the memory and working on them. I'm trying to do that in this way

Comment: Perhaps you should consider a local database that mirrors your main database, then you populate that at the start (with all data) and then work directly from the local DB... SQLite works quite well with MS SQL structures, and you can easily write a function that generically creates an SQLite clone based on a source database

Comment: Are you suggesting that you could code a more optimised method of outer joining large datasets than whatever DBMS you are using? This is the whole purpose of a database...

Comment: You are totally right, I agree that there is no better way to do joins than directly from the database, but I am trying to find a way to do this in program if it is possible... :/

Comment: @musefan If I load it in local database, can I use that for web applications? I am quite new in this, so don't mind me

Comment: You are doing this in a web application?!? You must have a lot of resources on your server... is the main database on a different server? Because if it's on the same one, and you are worried about workload of the server, then your web application isn't going to do any better... I think you have design problems and need to rethink, because you shouldn't be worrying about database server performance unless you have some design problems. How many users or queries are you expecting to be run, and how often?

Comment: I'm not sure if its going to be on the same server or not, I don't have that information yet. DataTable should load in the background, and than the app would use it. There is about 10 users in the same time querying the database. You think that it is not a good idea to work in this way?

Comment: You should not be doing this in a web app, really you'd need a really good reason to do this anywhere, this is literally what SQL is for and I would encourage you to just try and work with indexes and improve your DB performance so you can do this properly as your tables are not nearly large enough to warrant this. If you had to do it like this, and I think it would be a mistake, you could use a SortedDictionary with the key being your IDs and the value being an object holding the rows.  That would be pretty fast but you'd be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I understand :/ I will try to see if I can do it in the way you said, but if I can not, must find some other solution like dictionary or filtering. Anyhow, Thank you all for your time and tips :)